# Return an array value from cypress custom command and access it from test

Tags: cypress

Following value is being retrieved in a Cypress custom command,

```
listOfResults = [{"name":"x","amount":"99"}, {"name":"y","amount":"88"}]
```

and the command is,

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getResultList", (keyWord, ...args) => {
  var listOfResults = [];
  cy.get('[class="result"]')
    .each((resultItem) => {
      var singleResult = {};
      //Retrive Title
      cy.wrap(resultItem)
        .find('.name')
        .invoke("text")
        .then((val) => {
          const title = val.replaceAll("\n", "");
          singleResult.title = title;
        });
      //Retrive price
      cy.wrap(resultItem)
        .find('.price')
        .invoke("text")
        .then((val) => {
          const price = val.replaceAll("\n", "");
          singleResult.amount = price;
        });
      cy.then(() => {
        listOfResults.push(singleResult);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(listOfResults);//prints. correctly
      cy.wrap(listOfResults); 
      //tried also return cy.wrap(listOfResults);
    });
});
```

and in test, I am trying to access and store it.

```
//fetch all data in Search Results page and store it
      var resultList = cy.getResultList();
      cy.log("length:" + resultList.length);
```

But it is not getting stored and `resultList.length` logs `undefined`. How could we make the command to return a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In custom command you have to do:

```js
return cy.wrap(listOfResults)
```

Then in your test:

```js
cy.getResultList(keyWord, ...args).then((listOfResults) => {
  //Do something here with listOfResults
})
```

Since `wrap()` is returning a Cypress.Chainable, we can call `.then()` on our commands.

Comment: This works, and you can drop the whole `.then()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think just adding two returns will be ok,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getResultList", (keyWord, ...args) => {
  var listOfResults = [];
  return cy.get('[class="result"]')
    .each((resultItem) => {
      var singleResult = {};
      //Retrive Title
      cy.wrap(resultItem)
        .find('.name')
        .invoke("text")
        .then((val) => {
          const title = val.replaceAll("\n", "");
          singleResult.title = title;
        });
      //Retrive price
      cy.wrap(resultItem)
        .find('.price')
        .invoke("text")
        .then((val) => {
          const price = val.replaceAll("\n", "");
          singleResult.amount = price;
        });
      cy.then(() => {
        listOfResults.push(singleResult);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(listOfResults);//prints. correctly
      cy.wrap(listOfResults); 
      return cy.wrap(listOfResults); // this modifies the outer return
    });
});
```

Must be used in test with `.then()` like any command

```js
cy.getResultList(keyword).then(resultList => {
  ...
```

---

To illustrate better the point Alapan makes, in a custom command the result of the last command is automatically returned.

So this is the minimum needed for your command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getResultList", (keyWord, ...args) => {
  var listOfResults = [];
  cy.get('[class="result"]')
    .each((resultItem) => {
      var singleResult = {};
      //Retrive Title
      cy.wrap(resultItem)
        .find('.name')
        .invoke("text")
        .then((val) => {
          const title = val.replaceAll("\n", "");
          singleResult.title = title;
        });
      //Retrive price
      cy.wrap(resultItem)
        .find('.price')
        .invoke("text")
        .then((val) => {
          const price = val.replaceAll("\n", "");
          singleResult.amount = price;
        });
      cy.then(() => {
        listOfResults.push(singleResult);
      });
    })

  cy.wrap(listOfResults)  // last command, Cypress returns this

});
```

Comment: Thx this is a big help. We do a getInternalUrls method for aCypress command with this hint https://github.com/ncatestify/cypressio/blob/main/cypress/support/commands.ts